# Activation of network connection failed - Ubuntu 18.04 VM guest on Windows 10 Hyper-V Host

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, ubuntu, hyper-v

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 VM guest running in Windows 10 hyper-v.
The VM had previously been able to connect to the internet successfully. It recently stopped being able to connect and I cannot recall changing something.

It uses the `Default Switch` of Hyper-V .

Running `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` I get the following relevant messages.

> Oct 29 16:27:25 ubuntu-vm hv_kvp_daemon[318]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dns_info: not found

> Oct 29 16:27:25 ubuntu-vm hv_kvp_daemon[318]: sh: 1: /usr/libexec/hypervkvpd/hv_get_dhcp_info: not found

A Network notification also pops up in the VM desktop UI, that says

> Connection Failed

> Activation of network connection failed

I attach the pop up as an image for completeness.

What steps can I follow to connect the guest vm to the internet.

[image: Connection Failed. Activation of network connection failed]

Comment: Please feel free to ask for information that might help.

Comment: Check the Virtual Switch setup in Hyper-V Manager and all the settings. I have an External Switch (so bridged) and it remains working. Perhaps make sure the machine is safe, remove Hyper-V (Windows Features), restart, enable Hyper-V and restart again.

Comment: I tried many different settings, but nothing worked. However, after stopping Hyper-V service and restarting the machine completely It seems to work. Thank you @John , as your advice to "remove Hyper-V (Windows Features), restart, enable Hyper-V and restart again" was what inspired the restart service approach.

Comment: Thanks. I posted an answer and hopefully you will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Hyper-V here and all working well.

Check the Virtual Switch setup in Hyper-V Manager and all the settings. I have an External Switch (so bridged) and it remains working.

Perhaps make sure the machine is safe, remove Hyper-V (Windows Features), restart, enable Hyper-V and restart again.

What I have done in the past to gain access again from the guest machine was to disable the Hyper-V manager service in the host and restart the PC.The Hyper-V service was restarted automatically, with internet connection.